# Where's everybody hanging out?

Tags: discussion, chat

The [chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/240/code-golf) for this site is kinda dead. I'm guessing it's because everyone who would be chatting on this site is probably already in one or more rooms elsewhere in the SE network.

So, where is everybody? Only one room per answer, and one answer per room, please. This way we can get an idea, by votes, of which room generally has the most golfers.

I'd suggest this question get linked in the chat room description, so anyone stumbling across the room can easily find out where all the golfers really are. Or, of course, we could actually start using the chat room.

Answer (score 1):

I primarily hang out in [The DMZ](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/151/the-dmz).